# Variable size allocated during assign operation

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
     int a;
     char b,c;
     b=0x32;
     c=0x24;
     a=b*256+c;
     printf("a=%#x\n",a);
     return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a=0x3224
```

Size of `b` is 1 byte; `b*256` is a overflow for a `char` variable. Does the compiler allocate 2 different 16 bit registers for this operation? `int` is 16 bits over here.

Comment: Please put the newline at the end of the output, not at the beginning (I've fixed that, and made the format string match the claimed output, too).

Answer (score 6):

In the multiplication by the literal `256` on the following line, the `char` is promoted to an `int` before multiplication.

```
 a = b*256 + c;
```

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't overflow. Instead the contents of variable `b` (as well as `c`) are *promoted* to the type `int`.

Answer (score 2):

C language never performs arithmetic computations withing the domain of `char`, `short` or any other type that is smaller than `int`. Operands of arithmetic operators are promoted to `int` before the actual computations begin (assuming `int` can represent all values of the original type). So, your

```
a = b * 256 + c;
```

is actually interpreted by the compiler as

```
a = (int) b * 256 + (int) c;
```

In other words, expression `b *= 256` would indeed overflow a `char` variable on assignment back to `b`, but expression `b * 256` does not overflow by itself.